# How to deal with Pandas groupby choosing a different index type based on the data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've written some pandas code which does exactly what I want when there is data. However when there is no data, the code errors out. It turns out the `groupby()` is creating a different index type based on the data.

Here is the code:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
>>> a = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3]], columns=cols)
>>> b = pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=cols)
>>>
>>> a.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum().index
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2]],
           labels=[[0], [0]],
           names=['a', 'b'])
>>> a.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum().index.get_level_values('a')
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64', name='a')
>>>
>>> b.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum().index
Index([], dtype='object')
>>> b.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum().index.get_level_values('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/cv/.virtualenvs/ts/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2214, in get_level_values
    self._validate_index_level(level)
  File "/cv/.virtualenvs/ts/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1325, in _validate_index_level
    (level, self.name))
KeyError: 'Level a must be same as name (None)'
```

Questions:

- What are the rules that pandas uses to choose the type of index?
- I'd expect pandas to create a `MultiIndex` even with no data, since I explicitly `groupby()` several columns; why is it not creating a `MultiIndex`?
- My code is relying on the `groupby()` operation resulting in a `MultiIndex`; should I avoid doing this? If so, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's a really bizarre thing to do any operations on an empty DataFrame. There is a high likelihood that a better solution to your problem exists if you post the actual data and reason for wanting to do it this way.